# Regex not replacing value

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

In my code below, everything is working great except that the `$('#output').html(value.replace(/[\(\)\{\}\[\]\.\,\;\:\"\']/g, ''))` 
Won't replace those symbols, I'm not exactly sure why. I did some research and tried linking both of the replace's together, but that didn't work either.

```
function checkValue() {
var value = document.getElementById("thisinput").value;
var unspeakables = ['shout', 'message'],
    formatting = { 
        'shout' : {
            'color' : 'red'
        },
    };
$('#output').html(value.replace(/[\(\)\{\}\[\]\.\,\;\:\"\']/g, '')), 
$('#output').html(value.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + unspeakables.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b','gi'), 
function(matchedWord) {
    $('#output').css(formatting[matchedWord.toLowerCase()] || {});
    return '';
}));
```

I hope that someone can help me out!!

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call

```
$('#output').html(
```

twice. The second time, it replaces what's set the first time.

Instead of

```
$('#output').html(value.replace(/[\(\)\{\}\[\]\.\,\;\:\"\']/g, '')), 
$('#output').html(value.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + unspeakables.join('\\b|\\b')
...
```

you probably want

```
value = value.replace(/[\(\)\{\}\[\]\.\,\;\:\"\']/g, '')
.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + unspeakables.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b','gi'),
    function(matchedWord) {
        $('#output').css(formatting[matchedWord.toLowerCase()] || {});
        return '';
    }
);
$('#output').html(value);
```

Maybe you're confused by what does

```
value.replace(someRegex,someReplacement);
```

This **doesn't change** `value`, as a string in JavaScript is immutable. This **returns** a new string.

Comment: Very helpful and worked great. Thanks for the explanation! (waiting to accept the answer).